# Is std::promise<void> lock-free?

Tags: c++

Can I use `std::promise<void>` to signal from an interrupt handler to my worker thread? This would require that `std::promise<void>::set_value` doesn't block. Is that the case?

Comment: I don't understand why you need it to be `lock-free`. I believe you confuse unrelated things.